# To find And Update in Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

[image]

hi I have a excel with column A Title, and Column B Title Role, Column E Title Role Example. My Task is I have to find Title which contains Title Role Example if it contains than I have to update Title role with Title Role Example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that for each Title, you want to find if any Title Role Example is within that Title and then if it is, put that Title Role Example in the Title Role field.

You can do this with an array-entered formula. Double click in cell B2 so you're in edit mode, paste the following formula and then press Ctrl-Shift-Enter to confirm the formula as array-entered.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$2:$E$7,MATCH(FALSE,ISERROR(SEARCH($E$2:$E$7,A2)),0)),"")
```

If entered correctly, it should then appear with braces around it, which are put there automatically by Excel. Don't try to put them manually. Every time you change the formula, such as to update ranges, you need to recommit the formula using Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

After you've entered the formula for cell B2, then fill it down as normal.

Note that this formula will return the first matching Title Role Example. With your current order of Title Role Examples, "Manager" will be found before "Manager IT". So any kind of manager will return "Manager". You should put more specific Title Role Examples at the top so that they're found first. I.e., so the formula tries to find Manager IT first. If that can't be found, then it tries to find any Manager.

Comment: The formula should provide exactly what you're asking for. If none of the Title Role Examples are found in a particular Title, it returns a blank for that Title. Please fill the formula down to see that it provides what you're asking for when a Title Role Example is found.